# Mobile version of the website not updating on Chrome

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsiveness

I'm a novice at HTML and CSS and I launched a simple responsive website with only one page, but then I managed to add a couple of pages more to it after a few days. Everything looks good on desktop and when I make it smaller to 350px width via developer tools, it actually looks good as it should and all responsive.

Link: https://transporte.capital/

However, when I enter it from my mobile phone it looks horrible as CSS becomes almost inexistent. The logo becomes a link with underlines, the tweet widget is still there (I disabled it via display: none; in media queries because it takes too long to load), the social media section is distorted, all images are huge, and so on.

Is there something wrong with my mobile phone? I tried to look for cache in Site Settings - Data Stored in Chrome, but there was nothing for my website there.

Now I tried the Opera browser and the website looks good as it should. What should I do to make it update on Chrome? And will it update as it should the next time I make changes to it? Thank you!

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw8iv.jpg)
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qW7h.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could see the page properly in my Android mobile Chrome browser. Please clear cookies once and ensure the zoom in is not enabled. Attached is my screenshot. Screen size: 393x719px

[image]

Comment: Clearing cookies and cache worked, thanks!